# e.ctrlKey not working on firefox when clicking a select element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, dom-events

Most of the information is in the title.  I have tried the following code on edge/chrome as well as firefox.  In edge, it works as expected.  However, in firefox, if I hold down control while I click on the select element, `e.ctrlKey` shows false.  I have even tried writing my own ctrlKey by listening for keyup and keydown, but I have found that keyup doesn't even trigger while the select dialog box is open.  Do you why this could be happening, or how to fix it? Thanks!

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>
    </body>
    
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("click", (e)=> console.log(e.ctrlKey));
    </script>
</html>
```